# structure-map property injection for Attribute class with external dependency doesnt work for me

Tags: structuremap, property-injection

I am new to structure map. When I use property Injection for a Custom validation class the property is always null.
I think i am missing some thing. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.
I don't want to use System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(); to get the instance of logger in the AddressInfoValidator.
we are using MVC 5, FluentValidation.Mvc(5.1.0.0), and Structure map(2.6.3.0) for injecting dependencies.
I have a simple loging facade and a Myloger class:

```
  public class LogingFacade : ILogingFacade 
  {
     private IMyLoger loger;
     LogingFacade(IMyLoger myLoger)
     {
         this.loger = myLoger;
     }

    public void SaveToLog()
    {
        this.loger.SendError();
    }
 }
    public class MyLoger : IMyLoger 
   {

    public void SendError()
    {
        //send to DB
    }
}
```

The validator implimentation is as follows, I have used property injection because the class below will used as an Attribute:

```
public class AddressInfoValidator : AbstractValidator<AddressInfo>, IValidatorInterceptor
{
    public AddressInfoValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.StreetAddress).NotEmpty().Length(1, 50);
        this.RuleFor(x => x.UnitNumber).Length(0, 20);
        this.RuleFor(x => x.City).NotEmpty().WithMessage(UIErrorMessages.MSG_UI_00001).Length(1, 50).WithMessage(UIErrorMessages.MSG_UI_00002);
        this.RuleFor(x => x.State).NotEmpty();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.ZipCode).NotEmpty().Length(1, 20).Matches("\\d{5}");
    }

    [SetterProperty]
    public ILogingFacade Logger { get; set;}

   public ValidationResult AfterMvcValidation(ControllerContext controllerContext, ValidationContext validationContext, ValidationResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            result.Errors.ToList().ForEach(r =>
            {
                this.Logger.SaveToLog(new ValidationError { PropertyName = r.PropertyName, AttemptedValue = r.AttemptedValue, ErrorMessage = r.ErrorMessage });
            });
        }
        catch (System.AggregateException)
        {
            // TODO log the exception 
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ValidationContext BeforeMvcValidation(ControllerContext controllerContext, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return validationContext;
    }
}
```

The address model is :

```
    [Validator(typeof(AddressInfoValidator))]
    public class AddressInfo
    {
     public string StreetAddress{ get; set;}

      public string UnitNumber{ get; set;}
    public string ZipCode{ get; set;}

     public string City
     public string State{ get; set;}
}
```

Structure map registry called from application on start in global.asax:

```
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public class ServiceUiWebRegistry : Registry
    {
      public ServiceUiWebRegistry()
      {
        this.For<IMyLoger>().Use<IMyLoger>();
        this.For<ILogingFacade>().Use<LogingFacade>();
        this.FillAllPropertiesOfType<ILogingFacade>();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Do you see any logs? Structuremap throws exception with error codes if injection fails.

Comment: I am sorry, i am completely new to Structuremap, where can i see these logs? do i have to configure Structuremap to log errors?

Comment: No, AFAIK structuremap throws the exception and lets the host handle it. So can you check logs of your application?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions thrown until the run time error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.